# Facebook calendar exists, but won't display events in iOS 11.1

Tags: calendar, facebook

The Facebook calendar is checked (picture below), and while the events do appear on my laptop, they won't appear on my iPhone calendar.  I uninstalled Facebook and Messenger, then logged out of my gmail account to remove all calendars.  It was odd that when I did this, the Facebook calendar option stayed yet the rest left (second picture), but after reinstalling everything the events still won't show up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you logged in in iCloud (Apple ID) in iOS already ?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Thanks for you question Peter and for the first answer (kokernutz). (that really help me)
I cannot comment any answer, but IconDeamon must live in another planet.
Question made by Peter is in clear english and demonstrates the problem that the new release of IOS 11 bring with.
thank you kokernutz

Comment: Filipe Miranda - thanks so much for your support, I appreciate that.  After seeing IconDaemon's comment, I added in quite a bit more detail into my post, so I saw where he was coming from.  I'm glad the thread helped you :).

Answer (score 1):

On your desktop, Look in the right-hand pane on the Event page in Facebook. Find this section...

[image]

The last two links are webcal links which will let you subscribe via iCalendar on your Mac. Then, it will sync to your device if you have iCloud calendar sharing on. Roundabout, yes.